# Optimizing the execution time of the foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I use [XMLStreamer](https://github.com/BenMorel/XMLStreamer) for reading the XML file ([Structure here](https://pastebin.com/YxCcLicB)).

There are many products in 1 XML file (about 100,000 per file). The products have parameters, in total there are up to 500,000 of them in the file. There will be even around 20 XML files (maybe more, each with different products). **Will the database be a good place to store such data?**

**Main problem:**

The problem is the execution time of the script that enters the data into the database. Now with around 35,000 products, the time is around 300s. **How to optimize it?**

**Code:**

```php
try {
    $start = time();

    $mysqli->begin_transaction();
    $stmtProducts = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO products (shop_id, product_id, product_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
    $stmtProducts->bind_param("iis", $shopId, $productId, $productName);

    
    $streamer = new XMLStreamer('offer', 'products', 'product');
    foreach ($streamer->stream('bds.xml') as $product) {
        $document = new \DOMDocument();
        $document->appendChild($product);
        $element = simplexml_import_dom($product);
        $productId = $element->attributes()->id;
        $productName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($element->description->name);
        $stmtProducts->execute();
        
    }
   
    $stmtProducts->close();
    $mysqli->commit();
    var_dump("Time [s]:  " . (time() - $start));
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $exception) {
    $mysqli->rollback();
    throw $exception;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at prepared statements for your insert operations? That way, your script/the database does not have to parse the same command over and over again, but just needs to do it. I also think there are commands that delays the rebuilding of indices to 'once you are done'.

Comment: Please consider using prepared statements either way. Even if they won't improve performance, they will make the code cleaner with less chances of SQL injection.

Comment: How often are you running this? 300s once a month or even once a day isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: Instead of executing each statement, you can try `multiple-row insert` to speed up. It can be once per table or per 10,000 records.  Or use Prepare statement.  Or use LOAD DATA to speed up the insert.  Please check this -  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html

Comment: Using the `prepared statement` I got the time reduction by about a minute. Thank you for your valuable advice!
@ChrisHaas - is running once a day.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  The diagram you provided leaves out important info.

Comment: 20% improvement using prepared statements -- thanks for the datapoint.

Comment: you could also consider importing the xml lines one by one or in batch in a staging table and run a stored procedure with [XML functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html) to parse the xml lines and insert into the correct tables .. plus if you sha512 the lines so you can run and import / update only changes between the day before and the current day assuming you also have to update the information.

Answer (score 1):

Batch insert.

Instead of inserting one row at a time, insert 100 in a single `INSERT`.  This may shrink the 300 seconds to 30.

Re-think the `PRIMARY KEY` of the tables.  In order to do IODKU, you need to *not* specify the set of unique columns in the `UPDATE` part while specifying them in the `INSERT` part.  I would *guess* that some combination of the columns is really the PK.

**More**

It is quite strange to have

```
id
xx_id
xx_name
```

If `xx_id` is the `id` for xx_name, then you don't need `id`  If you also have

```
foo_id
```

then why have `xx_id`.

There are two main cases:

A simple mapping between a long string and a short "id" representing the string.  There may also be other info:

```
country_code CHAR(2),
country_name VARCHAR(100),
capital ...
```

In this case, `country_code` is used in other tables, and a `JOIN` is used to get the name for display purposes.  Or the name is used to get the matching code.

Another case:

```
company_id SMALLINT
branch_id TINYINT
number_of_employees SMALLINT
```

In this case, a composite PK seems useful: `PRIMARY KEY(company_id, branch_id)`

Comment: I added table structures to the first post and updated PHP code, it is now using `prepare statements`. 
`PK` is as separate column, because the table can repeat eg product_id, parameter_id, value_id (there are different products for each shop). So I decided to make a separate column for row identification. Is the database structure correct?
Is it possible to enter 100 lines in 1 query using a prepared statement?

Comment: I don't know of a good PHP way to use "prepare" for that.  I wish there were.  I added some other stuff to my Answer; you seem to have some misconceptions about ids.